# Scroll to middle when focus reaches to end of the screen in Java-Script

Tags: javascript

**Function:** I have added text-box and links on page. Each element on page have `tabIndex` assigned. You can tabout from text-box then by pressing up and down arrow keys we can traverse links.

**Problem:** I want to scroll window to middle when i reach at the end of screen. I have calculated offset to find out bottom but it works sometimes and not sometime.

**Note:** Mainly in chrome it works somehow do not how!! but this does not work with any other browsers.

https://jsfiddle.net/bat8bf8h/7/

**JavaScript Function:**

```
function abc(event) {
    // Find active Element tabIndex
    var tabIndexElement = document.activeElement.tabIndex;

    // tabIndex for element is 0 then send focus back to first search link
    if (tabIndexElement == 38) {
        document.querySelector('[tabIndex="2"]').focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // Based on Up and Down Key press move focus from next or previous search links
    if (event.keyCode == 38) { // up key press
        var queryString = '[tabindex="' + (--tabIndexElement) + '"]';
        var currentElement = document.querySelector(queryString);
        currentElement.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        // I will work on up event
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 40) { // down key press
        var queryString = '[tabindex="' + (++tabIndexElement) + '"]';
        var currentElement = document.querySelector(queryString);
        currentElement.focus();

        // This is what i think how can i approach this
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var rect = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        var offset = h - rect.top;
        currentElement.innerHTML = currentElement.innerHTML + ' offset:'+offset+' rectb:'+rect.bottom;
        if (offset < 0) {
            currentElement.innerHTML = currentElement.innerHTML + ' scroll';
            window.scrollTo(0, rect.top);
        } else {
            currentElement.innerHTML = currentElement.innerHTML + ' scroll1';
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance.